# Proving a sequence is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> I want to prove that (4n-1)/4n is bounded.

*My work:*

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{4n-1}{4n}\\
= &\frac{\frac{4n}n - \frac 1n}{\frac {4n}n}\\
=&\frac{4 - 1/n}4\\
=&1 - \frac 1{4n}\\
=&1\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; [\text{ by taking the limit}]
\end{align}$$
.

Comment: You now need to add that all convergent sequences are bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Split the fraction:

$$\frac{4n-1}{4n} = \frac{4n}{4n} - \frac{1}{4n}= 1-\frac{1}{4n} \le 1$$

since $\tfrac{1}{4n}$ is a positive term ($n \in \mathbb{N}$). The terms of the sequence are thus bounded above by 1.

Comment: No, that's not necessary.

Comment: Yes: the terms are clearly positive, so 0 is an obvious lower bound. Since the sequence is increasing, the greatest lower bound would be the first term.

Comment: It depends on what you want (or need) to prove. If you need to show a lower and an upper bound, then... you have to do both :-). But 0 as a lower bound is obvious and use my suggestion for the upper bound (you don't have to take limits).

Comment: This seems to be a new sequence/question? It's not very pratical to start asking new things via comments. In the same way:
$$\frac{4n-1}{2n} =\frac{4n}{2n} -\frac{1}{2n} = 2-\frac{1}{2n} \le 2$$

Comment: Yes, it's easier to just work with the general term of the sequence. Since $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\tfrac{4n-1}{4n}$ is clearly positive (so bounded below by 0) and it is bounded above by 1 because... _[proceed like in my answer]_; and you're done.

Comment: You're welcome.